# Matching the same symbols using stack in c++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, stack

So my assignment is about balancing symbols, instead of () for example it is ~~ and for {} it ^^, basically the symbols should match. , can someone help please?

A an example would be

```
 BinarySearchTree~~: root ^ nullptr ^
    ^
    ^
this should return true
```

This is the function that I wrote

```
bool balanced(std::string expression)

{
    int i;

    std::stack<char>check;

    char symbol;

    for (i=0; i<expression.length();i++)
    {
        symbol=expression[i];
        if(symbol=="~" || symbol=="^")
        {
            check.push(symbol);
        }
        if(check.empty())
              return false;
         else
              check.pop();
    }

    if(check.empty())
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Does your function work? If not, how doesn't it work? What problems does it give you? Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: My issue right now, I tested with a string that should return false but it always returns true.

Comment: Besides the logic which seems wrong, there are execution paths of the function that doesn't return a value. That means you have *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mean the following

```
bool balanced(const std::string &expression)
{
    std::stack<char> check;

    for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < expression.size(); i++)
    {
        char c = expression[i];

        if (c == '~' || c == '^')
        {
            if (!check.empty() && check.top() == c)
            {
                check.pop();
            }
            else
            {
                check.push(c);
            }
        }
    }

    return check.empty();
}
```

Take into account that for strings like this

```
"~^~^"
```

the result will be false. But when one pair of the symbols is enclosed in other pair of the symbols like

```
"~^^~"
```

the result will be true.

Comment: I understand. Thank you so so much. It makes perfect sense now.